# Should we close all NullReferenceException questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons, closed-questions

A really wide range of coding mistakes can generate the `NullReferenceException` (which, probably, is THE most asked question in SO), and we see so many questions on SO on a daily basis that are related to this. And a pattern I see is that most of the time people link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), and it gets closed as a duplicate pretty fast.

I agree that answering these questions don't really improve the quality of SO archives, but I do wonder if it should be the only goal of this site. As I mentioned, these questions are asked mostly by newcomers to programming, and it's not always easy or straightforward to link an error you get to a `NullReferenceException` even if you are directed to that question. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63252060/problem-in-getting-file-names-using-for-loop/63252183#comment111848854_63252183) is a good example that I came across today. Someone answered that question before it got closed, which is a pretty useful answer to a newcomer, but if it wasn't answered, taking into account the level of the OP, I don't think just the link to the NRE question would have helped them understand the cause.

So my question is, is it so bad that we answer these questions without them getting closed so that newcomers can get help?

Comment: No.  A generic "read all this stuff" answer is not helpful to people.  Particularized answers are the name of the game, even though for 'efficiency', some people want to close anything that looks like a duck.

Comment: I'm not sure that your example is a good example, ***literally the first point*** of the NPE canonical says: *"Object variables which are uninitialized and hence point to nothing"*. People need to be able to learn for themselves and not get handheld, if they can get all the way through the NPE post (while genuinely reading it and trying to understand it) then there's no reason that they can't edit their post to explain why they still need additional help.

Comment: @Nick, I disagree there. While what you say is technically true, if you put yourself in their shoes, reading, understanding, and breaking down the contents of a post like that and understanding how it relates to your own problem can be a daunting task for a newcomer. I don't see getting help from a more directed answer as 'being handheld'; I consider it more of a guided learning experience.

Comment: We really need a feature to close questions as duplicate + link to the appropriate answer. As of now, I usually close-vote and leave a comment pointing out which answer op has to read to find there problem. Answering every NPE question individually won't help anyone except op. I would even say it makes it harder for people coming from google to find a helpful answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, this is my thinking as well. I wish people weren't as happy as they are now to close down questions. As a 'have your cake and eat it too' resolution, wonder if the admins can make it so that it's still possible to answer closed questions for no reward points.

Comment: Not for every case, but if the "particularized" answer is "because x is null" and the generalised answer is a detailed explanation of what such an error means and how to debug it, the generalised one seems more helpful.

Comment: The same problem applies to a number of different topics though. For example: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?]

Comment: @BDL, how long is a closed question is still accessible? As I suggested before, what if that period is prolonged and during that time allows users to post answers without getting points? This way, a) quality of the archive is maintained, b) OP gets more detailed/directed help, and c) don't encourage people to answer post solely for points.

Comment: @BDL, _We really need a feature to close questions as duplicate + link to the appropriate answer._ It's already there? If you give the close reason as duplicate and link the post, it now automatically post a comment saying something along the lines of "Does this help your problem" and link to the post you linked.

Comment: @Sach: Are you sure that it links to the answer? And isn't the comment removed when the question get's closed (or not posted at all when you have a gold badge)? I meant something like a permanent link to a specific answer in the duplicate question

Comment: How helpful would it be for a user to find thousands of questions referencing a `NullReferenceException`? This would just drown the useful content in a lot of sand.

Comment: @BDL yeah I misread your comment. See mine above. That does seem like a good idea.

Comment: @Tom, this post is intended as a discussion to see if it's possible (and if people want to) find a solution to this. As I acknowledged in my post yeah it doesn't improve the quality of archives but I was wondering if there's a solution. One such as that pointed out by BDL, and another is what I suggested where we prolong the period a closed question remains accessible, and during that period let users answer the questions for no points so the OP get some more directed help.

Comment: I would close any question I see against that duplicate if the issue is in their code. The canonical has plenty of answers to work out what is wrong. If the null reference is triggered inside a library the OP doesn't seem to own, for example the stacktrace shows the bowels of the BCL, then closing as a duplicate is not correct, assuming it is clear from an MCVE that their vars to go into the API are not null.

Comment: @Sach, this would warrant an answer, but in a nutshell, many of us old devs started with "unmanaged" languages, where you did not get some kind of `FoolYouShippedWithSomeVexingException`, but a cold, hard crash. Thus, a tendency to close these things as *you don't know what you're doing*, now that there is no excuse for a programmer not to understand them.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, you probably just narrowed down the root cause of this problem as well as the general trend of SO which seems to put off a lot of newbies. I know that the SO management has been trying to address this issue for years without much success. It's a bit unwelcome to people who aren't good at programming, partly due to the reason you mentioned, and I dunno if it should be that way. I personally think it shouldn't, but my experience as well as most answers here seem to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @Sach New users are expected to adhere to the same standards as everybody else; that includes having at least a modicum of experience with programming. When questions are marked as duplicates, we don't (and *won't*) guarantee an answer they can just copy and paste. The expectation is that readers will be able to understand a more general answer and implement their own solution. That is *key* to SO.

Comment: @Sach, I understand your point of view, but IMHO we're not doing aspiring programmers any favor by refusing to explain things to them -- about machines, memory, and pointers -- just not to rustle their feathers. In the end of the day that is what they have to work with. Managed languages are easier because you get an exception instead of a crash, but untrained users keep asking about it. So what? Other languages like Rust abstract that, but you'll still find newcomers asking why `unwrap()` breaks their program. Again, so what? We cannot teach the basics, we can only help users grow from there.

Comment: A [mre], as minimal, is working code minimally extended to broken code. So these questions do not give MREs, they give dumps of disorganized code. If they didn't know their problem is an uninitialized pointer then after reading the canonical duplicate they do & they can find per their design where working goes broken & edit their post if they still have a question. If they already knew, they should already have done that, and should do it. I would agree typically their design & program are messes but then they should ... ask re code that is working code minimally extended to broken code.

Comment: If users cannot step-debug to find out, even roughly, where the bad pointer/reference is coming from, they cannot program computers.  Yes, sometimes it's difficult, eg when the bad reference stems from a bad argument to some factory function, but posters need to come up with more than a stack trace and 'help, I have no clue':(

Comment: I mean, I would be happy with the head of a trace, some code and some sign of understanding, say 'I found my Groggit instance bad.  It was returned from the GroggitLookup() with what seems to be good arguments.  What might I do to debug this further?'

Answer (score 20):

I don't think that we should be answering the *same* question, asked with OP's flavor of object names, every single time.

The problem here is that (and this occurs with Java too) NullReferenceExceptions are fairly routine - someone didn't initialize an object, or it's initialized to `null` or its equivalent, and they tried to dereference it.  Routine rookie mistake, no doubt.

*However*, the fact that it is a routine rookie mistake makes it an exceptionally good question to canonicalize, which is what the duplicate closure is making obvious.

**We are not here to kowtow to beginners of a language, domain, framework or subject.**  We are here to answer questions.  If a beginner cannot understand the answer to our question, I would ***strongly*** argue that this is outside of our scope to handle, since we can't control what beginners do and don't understand.

<sup>Should Stack Overflow seek to *change* that scope, I'll be expecting my full compensation up front before hand-holding beginners.  Just an FYI.</sup>

Comment: I understand that we are looking at this problem from a fundamentally different viewpoint. And it's hard to come to common grounds when that's the case. I still hope that SO look at this problem (and I'm happy that they have been trying - albeit mostly unsuccessfully - to address the issue of SO being unfriendly at best and downright hostile at worst towards beginners.

Comment: @Sach:  I'd be a lot *less* hostile about being treated as a free tutor for beginners if I were compensated.  Feel like opening up your wallet? 

Comment: Again, fundamental differences. I'm much more happy to devote my time free of charge while you're not. Neither is wrong.

Comment: @Sach This isn't hostility. It's *curation*. The goal has *never* been to help everyone with their programming problems. It's *always* been to become a repository of knowledge that will help far more people over time than specific one shot answers. Closing as duplicate is trying to *help* them.

Comment: I would disagree.  It's not that we're coming at this from differences of opinion, @Sach. I'm coming at this from established precedent over the last twelve or so years of how Stack Overflow has operated, whereas others are believing that the scope should soften to allow for a more interpersonal relationship with beginners so that they can use us as a way to help jump-start their career or understanding of programming.  I'm only saying, 'If that's the way we're moving, then I'm going to need $$$ before I agree to this.'

Comment: @fbueckert, closing isn't necessarily hostile, but I've seen enough of hostile attitude from users even if it's a most basic mistake the newcomers make.

Comment: @Sach:  Do we call them outside of their display name?  Do we insult their intelligence?  Do we hurl abuse at them?  All of those things should be reported so that the jerks who do that are dealt with.  Downvoting/closing as a dupe?  That's not hostile.  One is simply *interpreting* it as an act of hostility.

Comment: @Makoto In other words, we didn't sign up to be tutors. If SO wants us to be, they can pony up the cost of hiring them.

Comment: @Makoto, the SO management(?) has been trying to move it towards that direction though, although not working. Maybe you might need to talk to them about it. :)

Comment: @fbueckert:  Exactly!

Comment: @Sach:  I would but I don't think they listen so well.  Or, they listen but react to parts of our message from an emotional perspective.  I've got enough on my plate to disincentivize me from trying to continue to explain to our benevolent dictators how most of their ideas fly in the face of what some of us started to contribute to the network for in the first place.

Comment: Well, some-others-of-us started with slightly different ideas, so I've not complaints in that regard.

Comment: Well, it's not even an entirely rookie mistake.  Every experienced developer has attempted to dereference an invalid pointer/reference many, many times, ('oh shit, I forgot to create the Werble instance, mutter...mutter').  It happens so frequently that I often know immediately what I have, (not:), done as soon as the AV box appears:(   It is unrealistic to do any more than point at the canonical answer.